# I want to make gui application for sorting in python with Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have written this code and in this the function gen() id used to generate numbers at random for sorting. My code is like

```
from Tkinter import *
import random

class Sorting( Frame ):
   def __init__( self ):
      Frame.__init__( self )

      self.master.title( "Sorting" )
      self.master.rowconfigure( 5, weight = 1 )
      self.master.columnconfigure( 5, weight = 1 )
      self.grid( sticky = W+E+N+S )

      #label for sort intro      
      self.label1 = Label( self, text = "Select Sort", width = 25 , height=2)
      self.label1.grid( row = 0, column = 1, sticky = N )

      #Radio buttons for sorts
      self.button1 = Radiobutton( self, text = "Bubble Sort" )
      self.button1.grid( row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W+E+N+S )

      self.button2 = Radiobutton( self, text = "Quick Sort" )
      self.button2.grid( row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W+E+N+S )

      self.button3 = Radiobutton( self, text = "Shell Sort" )
      self.button3.grid( row = 1, column = 2, sticky = W+E+N+S )

      #label to store value
      def gen():
         for x in range(0,10):
            num=random.randint(0,100)
            self.label2 = Label( self,text='%s'%num, width = 2, height = 2 )
            self.label2.grid( row =3 , columnspan =10 , sticky = W+E+N+S )

      #button to generate number
      self.button4 = Button( self,text='Generate no.', command=gen )
      self.button4.grid( row = 2,column=1, sticky = W+E+N+S )
      self.rowconfigure( 5, weight = 1 )
      self.columnconfigure( 5, weight = 1 )

def main():
   Sorting().mainloop()   

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

I want to use it for generating random numbers and then sorting them. Any suggestion to do it.

Comment: 1) you should explain better what you want to obtain. A sketch would help. 2) you want to edit your code and fix indentation errors.

Comment: i edited it can you now check it

Comment: It is not still well indented. If you were using standard 4 spaces indent instead of 2 if would be more evident to you eyes where the problem is. This is a practical proof of the advantages of following PEP-8 style guide advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
  #label to store value
  def gen():
      self.nums = []
      for x in range(0, 10):
          self.nums.append(random.randint(0, 100))
      # . . . . . . . . . .  .    <- maybe here call sorting method on self.nums
      num = ''.join('%4i' % num for num in self.nums)
      self.label2 = Label( self, text=num, width=2, height=2)
      self.label2.grid(row=3, columnspan=10, sticky=W+E+N+S)
```

The values to sort are stored in `self.nums`. You want to call your sorting algorithm to that list before showing them in the label.

[image]

I tried to keep your code as it was as much as possible. From this point it can be further optimized. For example, you could substitute:

```
  self.nums = []
  for x in range(0, 10):
      self.nums.append(random.randint(0, 100))
```

with

```
  self.nums = [random.randint(0, 100) for x in range(10)]
```

Comment: @user1155111 Perfect! see my last edit also. You should accept the answer as the best (click on the mark below the vote arrows). You have not accepted yet any on the answers you have got to your other questions.

Comment: I have asked something  else below that how can i use array of one function in another